# iPhone AppStore always asks for password when redeeming

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

Basically what the title says; when I'm redeeming a code in the AppStore, there's no option for me to authenticate via TouchID, it always asks me for my Apple ID password. Am I missing something?

It's not really a HUGE deal, just a little annoying. Also curious that Apple lets you use TouchID for PAYMENTS but not when redeeming codes.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The prompt to enter your password shows you the Apple ID that you are using and for people that use more than one ID - it's quite helpful to prevent inadvertent redemption of money. I agree for some people it would be easier to just use the fingerprint, but I've seen cases where $100 gift cards went to the wrong account and it was a hassle to correct it.

Comment: Couldn't they just tie a TouchID to a specific apple id?

Comment: @zaxvo Apple could implement that, but so far they haven't.